# Indentation in Latex

Tags: latex, indentation

In the following Latex code, I would like to indent second row from start of `m\angle` BTS in the first row, i.e. after `\therefore` in the first row. I tried with `\phantom{\therefore}`, but it does not work.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

```tex
\begin{aligned} \\
& \therefore m\angle BTS+m\angle TSE+ \\
&\phantom{\therefore}m\angle SEB+m\angle EBT=360^\circ
\end{aligned}
```

The expected result should be:

```
∴ m∠BTS = m∠BES =
  m∠EBT = m∠EST
```

(i.e. expecting indentation for the 2nd row)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have any alignment characters (the `&`) in your example – the point of the `{aligned}` environment (this is an `amsmath` document, yes?) is to line those up.  The best thing to do would be to check the amsmath documentation, and follow the examples in there.
2. In general, LaTeX-related questions are better asked on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com).